# Video compression changes custom tab bar in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented a custom tabbar in my app. Where I can scroll on the tab, and also the tab can have more than 5 buttons. The problem is when i pick a video with imagepickercontroller, the compressing video dialog box shows up. The video is compressed and when the imagepicker is dismissed, my custom tabBar gets distorted. The default tabbar shows at the bottom of the screen along with my custom tabbar. And this problem is only when i run the app on iOS 5 device. Please help me out here, either tell me how to avoid compression (tried setting the video quality to 'HIGH'), or some way around the compression thing.